# expression result unused in a strcmp

Tags: c, boolean, cs50

I am trying to get the code to compare user entered strings with the user's command line strings. I have tried other ways and i thought this would be easier considering its coded practically the same and is just checking to see if the string entered is one of the previous strings, and if it isn't it's supposed to return false but continue the loop until it has checked all of the users command line strings.

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) //loop through all the candidates
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0) //this part works however alone it considers all user strings to be true that's why I added the other code to have it check if the users string does not exist and if so it would return false
        {
        candidates[i].votes++;
        return true;
        }
        else (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0); //expression result unused?
        {
        return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I don't understand why it is out putting expression result unused, when I am telling it to return back to the loop after it has tested that string. What I have is supposed to check each of the users string one at a time and then say whether that person exits or if they don't exist and skip that vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C expects a statement after an `else`, not a condition as in an `if`. In this code:

```
else (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0);
```

the compiler interprets `(strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0);` as an expression statement. Commonly, expression statements are used to assign values (as in `x = 3;`) or to call functions (as in `printf("Hello, world.\n");`). Any expression may be used as a statement, so `(strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0);` is allowed as the statement after an `else`.

However, the compiler sees that the results of this expression is not used. It does not assign or modify a value, and it does not call a function with side effects, and it does not have any other side effects. So the compiler warns you that its result is unused.

An `else` statement does not accept a condition to be evaluated; its statement is simply executed if the `if` condition fails. Whenever there is a choice between two alternatives, we use `if (condition) statement1 else statement2`, and `statement2` is always executed if `condition` is false. Only if there are three or more alternatives would you use additional conditions, and these would be included by compounding `if` statements, as in `if (condition1) statement1 else if (condition2) statement2 else statement3`. Your code has only two alternatives, so it would use the simpler form.

Then we would have:

```
if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
{
    candidates[i].votes++;
    return true;
}
else
{
    return false;
}
```

That fixes the “expression result unused” message, but then another problem arises. This is not the code you want. This code causes the routine to return `false` as soon as it sees a candidate in the array that does not match the `name` parameter. That is not what you want to do. When a name in the array does not match the `name` parameter, you want to go on to the next element in the array, continuing the loop. You do not want to return, so remove the `return` statement. The `else` clause is not needed at all, and the code can be just:

```
if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
{
    candidates[i].votes++;
    return true;
}
```

Then the loop will continue. If, in a later iteration, a matching name is found, that candidate’s votes will be incremented, and the routine will return. If the loop finishes without finding a match, the code will continue to the `return false;` that is outside the loop, and that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo at the end of the line.

```
 else (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0); //expression result unused?
                                            ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0); //expression result unused?
```

The "expression result unused" because you don't need to write it - it's already implicit from the above `if` condition:

```
    if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
    {
        candidates[i].votes++;
        return true;
    }
    else //<-- this else without any expression having the same result
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Actually you don't even need to write `else` at all. This would have same effect:

```
for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) //loop through all the candidates
{
    if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0)
    {
        candidates[i].votes++;
        return true;
    }
}
return false;  //<-- this return is enough
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. While the second `strcmp` is redundant, that is not the cause of the compiler warning message. Also, the allegation that remove the `else` “would have the same effect” is incorrect. It changes the behavior of the program, albeit to the desired behavior from a buggy behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The else statement may not use a condition like in your function

```
else (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0); //expression result unused?
```

Moreover there is a semicolon after the condition.

It seems you mean

```
else if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0) //expression result unused?
{
    return false;
}
```

However it is enough to write syntactically

```
else
{
    return false;
}
```

But logically it is incorrect. Because if the first candidate is not the same as the specified name other candidates will not be considered.

The function could be written the following way

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    int i = 0;
    
    while ( i < candidate_count && strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0 ) i++;

    if ( i != candidate_count ) candidates[i].votes++;

    return i != candidate_count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be reformatted to the form:

```
bool vote(string name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < candidate_count; i++) //loop through all the candidates
    {
        if (strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) == 0) //this part works however alone it considers all user strings to be true that's why I added the other code to have it check if the users string does not exist and if so it would return false
        {
            candidates[i].votes++;
            return true;
        }
        else  
        {
            strcmp(name, candidates[i].name) != 0; //expression result unused
        }

        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I think the issue is very easy to spot.
You have another issue here as well. If the first `strcmp` does not return 0, the for loop will stop (on the first iteration) with `return false`